# Dimensions different after performing the same preprocessing with CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am confused with how my test and training sparse matrices have different number of features after performing the same preprocessing

this is preventing me from predicting my test data

```
def vectorizer(X):
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
    vectorizer.fit(X)
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
    
    return X
```

```
other_features = ["n_steps", "n_ingredients"]
features = df_train[other_features]
test_features = df_test[other_features]

name = vectorizer(df_train.name)
steps = vectorizer(df_train.steps)
ingr = vectorizer(df_train.ingredients)


test_name = vectorizer(df_test.name)
test_steps = vectorizer(df_test.steps)
test_ingr = vectorizer(df_test.ingredients)

X = hstack([steps,ingr, name, np.array(features)])
X_test = hstack([test_steps, test_ingr, test_name, np.array(test_features)])
```

```
clf = LogisticRegression(C = 0.01, max_iter = 1000000, penalty = 'l2')
clf.fit(X, y)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
```

the error raised during prediction:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-1534a274c605> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = clf.predict(X_test)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in predict(self, X)
    305             Predicted class label per sample.
    306         """
--> 307         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    308         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    309             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    284         n_features = self.coef_.shape[1]
    285         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
--> 286             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
    287                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    288 

ValueError: X has 16417 features per sample; expecting 31765
```

Comment: You're making a new vectorizer separately for your training and test data. I don't know why you think it wouldn't be different. Vectorize and then split.

Comment: the training and test data came in separate files, I have to train the model with training data before predicting the test data

Answer (score 2):

You must use the same `CountVectorizer` instance for both datasets. When you use the `.fit_transform` method, the transformer internally stores the transformation that it learned, so that it can be re-applied later.

In your code, not only are you creating a new `CountVectorizer` instance for every data set, you are also freshly training it on every data set. If you think of "test" data as an approximation of "out of sample" data (i.e. data that you do not currently have), you should see why doing it your way makes no sense, which is why you are getting nonsense results.

Correct usage would look something like this:

```py
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
classifier = LogisticRegression(C = 0.01, max_iter = 1000000, penalty = 'l2')

x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred_train = clf.predict(x_train)

x_test = vectorizer.transform(data_test)
pred_test = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Note that in your case you might want to also use of [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) and [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer).

I recommend reading [this guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html) for more information.

Comment: You'd need to fit the vectorizer on both the training and test data, which have different features, or transforming the test data won't capture many features.

Comment: @CJR that's not how it works. If the feature isn't in your training data, you can't magically add it when it appears in out-of-sample data at prediction time, unless you re-train the model on the out-of-sample data, at which point it is no longer "out-of-sample" data and it is no longer "at prediction time". There are some techniques to work around this problem (like feature hashing), but you can't just pretend like the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: The features that aren't in the training data won't contribute to the model (they're all 0; features with no variance aren't useful for prediction). You aren't magically adding anything.

Comment: @CJR yes, you are magically expanding the size of your vocabulary. If you have a known vocabulary ex-ante, use that instead of inferring it from the training data. And those 0 features should all get 0 weights anyway in which case they're doing literally nothing and there's no point in even having them.

Comment: You're assuming that the things you just said are intuitive and someone training a model will know them already. Clearly that is not true or this question wouldn't have ever been asked. I can think of several good reasons to align training/test features (maybe you want to do a similarity metric between your test and training data, which is probably a useful visualization if they're not the result of splitting a unified data set). It's not information leakage and a useful clarification.

Comment: Sure, that's a useful technique; go ahead and post that as another answer if you want. I won't add it to my answer because I think it does not demonstrate the typical entry-level usage of Scikit Learn APIs, and the question looks like an entry-level regression question to me.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorize your testing data with the vectorizer you fit to your training data. Otherwise the input encoding isn't the same, so anything your model learned on the first dataset is irrelevant.

As to why it's a different length: the number of unique (non-excluded) words becomes the length of the vector when you fit the vectorizer. If there's a word in one or the other that is only in one data point, it will be missing from the other one. So the two don't have the same number of unique words, and they end up different lengths.

So tl;dr. Fit once, use twice.

```
count = CountVectorizer()
count.fit(X_train)
X_train_vec = count.transform(X_train)
X_test_vec = count.transform(Y_train)
```

If you want to automate that you can put it in a pipeline.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(('count', CountVectorizer()),
                    ('model', [yourmodel])

# Regression predictions
Y_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
Y_test = pipeline.transform(X_test)

test_acc = metrics.accuracy(X_test, Y_test, Y_test_labels) # Or whatever metric
```